# How to query in mongodb programmatically?

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor

I wannt to create code like this:

```
var result = Attributes.find({
    attribute_name : {
    $exist : true,
    $in : [1]
 }
});
```

but programmatically, so i ceate code like this:

```
var genQuery = '{ "' + by + '" : { "$exists" : true, "$in" : [' + data + ']} }';
var result = Attributes.find(genQuery);
```

but I get error maximum call stack

because result of JSON.parse(genQuery)

```
{ _id: { '$exists': true, '$in': [ 1 ] } }
```

How to query in mongodb programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `genQuery` variable you declare is a String, but you cannot pass strings as selectors or modifiers in `find()` functions.
You should create an Object to make it works:

```
var genQuery = {};
//use this notation to declare a new object key depending on a variable
genQuery[by] = {
  $exists: true, 
  $in: [1]
};

var result = Attributes.find(genQuery);
```

Comment: I tested it in an existing collecting, it should work, do you get any error?

Comment: still same "maximum call stack"

Comment: when i console log it, same like this : { _id: { '$exists': true, '$in': [ 1 ] } }
there '' surround $exist

Comment: remove the ' ' for $exists and $in, they are object keys not string.

Comment: var stringQuery = '{ "' + by + '" : {}}';
        var genQuery = JSON.parse(stringQuery);
        genQuery[by] = {
            $exists: true,
            $in: [data]
        };
console.log(genQuery);
        var result = Attributes.find(genQuery);
that's my code, actually i didnt use ''. but when i console log it added automatically

Comment: As I show in my answer you don't need JSON.parse, just create an Object directly, instead of writing some kind of "object like string" and then parse it.